# When I using strings Command in Ubuntu16 to find something, I got nothing output

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, libstdc++

When I run this command in ubuntu16:

```
strings /media/zhanggy/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-11.2.0-h1234567_1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.29 | grep GLIBCXX
```

I got nothing output.

[here is the information picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jvgo.png)

Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

Possibly because this version of `libstdc++` was built with symbol versions disabled.

You could also try `strings -a ...` and see if that changes anything.

> How can I fix this?

Why do you believe there *is* anything to fix here? [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?